# Python Bokeh, Google Maps API Patch Doc error

Tags: python, google-visualization, bokeh, patch

I am trying to create a geographic visualization using bokeh and then integrate my bokeh server app into flask to deploy it on a VPS. Here is a part of my code,

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.686293, lng=-97.3614409, map_type="roadmap", zoom=13)
p = gmap(google_api_key="My Google Maps API Key", map_options=map_options, title="Resolutions Clients", plot_width=1000, plot_height=600)
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

When run independently my code produces the necessary visualization but, gives the following error in the command line,

```
error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'google_api_key' and 'map_options'
```

The error is occuring at the gmap call. I'm getting stuck trying to integrate my bokeh server app into flask because of the above error. I tried looking this error up and found a few relevant results all of which pointed to bugs in the Bokeh library, but I did'nt really find anything that is directly relevant to my problem (use of bokeh with Google Maps API). Any help on navigating this issue is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*(As a general courtesy to the people who are answering questions gratis on SO, please pare your code down to a **minimal** example)*

I'm not sure what is going on, but the message persists with this minimal code:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.686293, lng=-97.3614409, map_type="roadmap", zoom=13)
p = gmap(google_api_key="My Google Maps API Key", map_options=map_options, title="Resolutions Clients", plot_width=1000, plot_height=600)
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

It seems that the message does not actually affect the proper display or operation of the Bokeh app, so I would say for now it can be safely ignored. However, spurious errors or warnings are bugs, so I would encourage you to file a [GitHUb bug report issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the note, bigreddot and my apologies for including unnecessary code. I have edited my code as per your suggestion.